# ABS working fine on 4.1 but it's throwing exception when it runs on 2.2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am learning How to use ABS. The code is working fine on 4.1 but when I ran the same code on 2.2, it's throwing exception

This is MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Beauty").setTabListener(new Listner()));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Cookery").setTabListener(new Listner()));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Health").setTabListener(new Listner()));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Relationship").setTabListener(new Listner()));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Yoga Spirituality").setTabListener(new Listner()));
    }

    class Listner implements TabListener {

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new BEAUTYFragment());
                    ft.commit();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new COOKERYFragment());
                    ft.commit();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new HEALTHFragment());
                    ft.commit();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new RELATIONSHIPFragment());
                    ft.commit();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new YOGAFragment());
                    ft.commit();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { }
    }
}
```

This is manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sher"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error in LogCat:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a ABS theme or let your theme extend from an ABS theme. Required to handle  backward compability of the ActionBar (pre 3.0 devices)

e.g.

```
<application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Here is some information regarding [ABS-theming](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)

Comment: But it showing error "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock')"

Comment: Try this value '@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'

Comment: Please help me How to add theme resources? it is showing "No resource found error"

Comment: probably somehting wrong with your abs configuration. Have you referenced it as a library project? (does your activity extend from some kind of ABS-object?) edit: also do a clean on your workspace

Comment: yeah I referred,but when I checked that was "red crossed" so I had added those library into "libs" and then build the path.